# Amazon Lex version 2

Tags: aws-sdk-js

Does the @aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service works with the recently deployed new version 2 of Amazon Lex?

Can't seem to make Amazon Lex 2 work using AWS Amplify interactions library. I am check on @aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service if it works with version 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. Spent half a day scouring the internet for the same answer. Looks like we have to use this instead:

[AWS.LexRuntimeV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntimeV2.html)

Comment: I will check on that documentation again. Were you able to make it work?

Comment: Got message from Amplify team, the interactions library is not compatible with Amazon Lex 2. They already have it as feature request and will be be implementing it at some point in the future. No definite timeline. Hope they post updates soon

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the update. I was able to use the LexRuntimeV2 API.